# Склонение имени Стася

Tags: склонение, падежи, ономастика

Имя Стася как будет в различных падежах?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего особенного, склоняется так же, как Вася, например:

*им. — Стася

род. — Стаси

дат. — Стасе

вин. — Стасю

тв. — Стасей/Стасею

предл. — Стасе*